# Delphi OpenTools API - Editing the project requires clause

Tags: delphi, ide, wizard, opentools

I have written an OpenTools wizard for creating a skeleton for a custom project type.  It does work, and the project and units are properly created.  But, how do I edit the .dpk or .dpk file's requires clause?

A call to `ModuleServices.CreateModule(MyIOTAProjectCreatorInterface)` gives me the .dproj file only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my [VCL Component Installer](http://www.rvelthuis.de/programs/compinstall.html) (since XE, this is part of the Delphi IDE), I do it this way:

```
procedure TCompInstallWizard.AddReferenceFiles(InstallProject: IOTAProject;
  const FileNames: array of string);
var
  ReferenceFile: string;
begin
  WriteDebugMessage('AddReferenceFiles');
  for ReferenceFile in FileNames do
    if not ContainsFile(InstallProject, ReferenceFile) then
      InstallProject.AddFile(ReferenceFile, False);
end;
```

with the help of function `IOTAProject.AddFile(FileName, IsUnitOrForm)`. Note that I call it like this:

```
if FPersonality = ppCppBuilder then
  AddReferenceFiles(InstallProject,
    ['rtl.bpi', 'designide.bpi', 'vcl.bpi', 'vclactnband.bpi',
     'vclx.bpi', 'xmlrtl.bpi'])
else
  AddReferenceFiles(InstallProject,
    ['rtl.dcp', 'designide.dcp', 'vcl.dcp', 'vclactnband.dcp',
     'vclx.dcp', 'xmlrtl.dcp']);
```

Note that the docs say:

```
{ Call this function to add an arbitrary file to the project.  NOTE: some
  files have special meaning to different projects.  For example: adding
  VCL60.DCP will cause a new entry in a package project's "requires" list
  while it will be a raw file to any other project type.  Set IsUnitOrForm
  to true for files that are considered items that the project would
  process directly or indirectly (ie. .pas, .cpp, .rc, etc..) or can be
  opened in the code editor. For all others, including binary files
  (.res, .bpi, .dcp, etc..) set this to False. }
procedure AddFile(const AFileName: string; IsUnitOrForm: Boolean);
```

This means that if you add a `'bla.dcp'` it will automatically land in the `requires` section, and if you add a `'bla.pas'` file, it will land in the `contains` section. It took me a while to find out.

Comment: Perfect, very helpful, Thanks Rudy.